# Generic extension method to map values from one array to another C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a generic extension to create an array of `MyClass()` from an array of integers.

This is what I think the method call should look like:

```
MyClass[] myClassArray = intArray.MapValues(x => new MyClass(x));
```

And here is my best guess at what I need to do:

```
public static TTarget[] MapValues<TSource, TTarget>(this TSource[] source, Func<TSource, TTarget> operation) {
                
    TTarget[] target = new TTarget[source.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) {            
        target[i] = operation; // problem is here "Cannot convert type Func<TSource, TTarget> to TTarget"
    }
    
    return target;
}
```

I don't think that `Func<TSource, TTarget> operation` is what I need in this case but I am new to extension methods and haven't been able to find anything helpful on the internet (not sure what to search for).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `operation(source[i])` will invoke function for the given item

Comment: You can just use "select" instead of your own extension method.

Comment: @YegorAndrosov got rid of the errors, unfortunately I am not in a place where I can run the code. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi I tried select but couldn't seem to get it working, how would I do that?

Comment: Try this : MyClass[] myClassArray = intArray.Select(x => new MyClass()).ToArray();

Comment: @Commonaught The documentation, as well as lots of sites all around the internet (including this one), are full of examples of using `Select`.

Comment: If you want to make it a generic extension, you may have to make use of Reflection to get the type and correspondingly create an instance of that type at runtime. Do you really have the necessity here to use generics?

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdithat seems to work, thanks

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi: you should post that as an answer.  It might be useful to the next person who comes up with something like that.  It's certainly up-voteable and *so* much simpler that what the OP wanted to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write any extension method and you can use "Select" like this:

```
MyClass[] myClassArray = intArray.Select(x => new MyClass()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This method already exists:

```
MyClass[] myClassArray = Array.ConvertAll(intArray, x => new MyClass(x));
```

(You can also use `.Select`, but the output of that isn't an array... and if you combine it with `.ToArray` it will still be less efficient than `Array.ConvertAll`)